# how to add 2 dynamic textboxes values in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

i want addition of 2 textboxes values by jquery here is my code it is working but just only for the first row i want it also for the 2nd or third row here is the screen shot you can see that what i really want. Thanks
[image]

```
<?php
  $query3 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from orders") or die("sdfsfs");
    while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
    {
        $item_description = $row3['item_description'];
        $quantity = $row3['quantity'];
        $unit_price = $row3['unit_price'];
?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="form-control" style="box-shadow:none;border:0px solid black;"><?php echo $row3['id']; ?></label></td>
        <td width="400"><textarea name="desc" class="form-control" style="box-shadow:none;border:0px solid black;"><?php echo $item_description; ?></textarea></td>
        <td><input id="quant" class="form-control common" name="quant" style="box-shadow:none;border:0px solid black;" type="text" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>"/></td>
        <td><input id="unit_price" class="form-control common" name="unit_price" style="box-shadow:none;border:0px solid black;" type="text" value="<?php echo $unit_price; ?>"/></td>
        <td><input id="total" readonly class="form-control" name="total" style="box-shadow:none;border:0px solid black;" type="text" value=""/></td>
        <td><span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>


<script>
        $('#total').val(parseFloat("0"+$('#quant').val()) * parseFloat("0"+$('#unit_price').val()));
        $('.common').change(function () {
        $('#total').val(parseFloat("0"+$('#quant').val()) * parseFloat("0"+$('#unit_price').val()));
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through each tr and get your total value and add them and use element.html() method to show. Inside your main jquery method use something like following.

```
.............
...........
var total=0
    $('#yourTableID tr').each(function() {
        var sub_t = $(this).find(".yourTotalTDClassName").html();    
    //parse subt_t into integer and then add
    total=total+sub_t;
     });
    $("#resultElement").val(total); // or .html() based on your element
```

I am using my cell phone, So please consider typos and syntax errors. For this you need to define a class for each  tag containing your total amount and use that class name to get all td values to get total amount. Try on your own first and If still you face problem then I can post full code including html.

Answer (score 0):

Each row in your table is populated with the same ID. You need to have unique ID's.